# Save a List<T> not serialisable to a file

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, serialization, datagrid

I would like to save and restore the size and order of columns datagrid on a WPF application.
I store this data on two lists :

```
List<DataGridColumn>
List<SortDescription>
```

DataGridColumn and SortDescription are MSDN class not serialiable.
I would like to save these list in a file ( xml or txt...)

What is the simplest way please ?

Best regards,
Nixeus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it as e.g.

```
List<Tuple<string, ListSortDirection, int, etc.>>
```

where string is column name and ListSortDirection specifies sort direction, int is index etc. You can easily serialize such type.

Comment: And with this, i need to create a serialisable class even?

Comment: Depends on what kind of serialization are you performing. If you do some custom serialization you do not need new class. If you use XmlSerializer you will need extra class where you will mark the members with attributes like XmlElement, XmlAttribute...

Comment: And I would strongly recommend to create extra class with members you want serialize.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly urge you to not save it as a list of `DataGridColumn` or `SortDescription`.

Instead you should create your own lightweight POCO that is agnostic to the technology and contains the data needed to recreate the column layout. Because this is your own data object it is serializable any way you like, but better still it is not tied directly to the Microsoft DataGrid. This way if you ever swap out the Microsoft (WPF Extended  Toolkit) grid then your column settings will be easily transferred to the new grid you use.

When you rehydrate your list of data objects from whereever you store it, you can simply iterate through the list, creating one column for each data object, and set the appropriate column values.

Comment: So it's better to juste save, width and display index ?

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni That's right. You might also need sort direction (none, asc, desc, etc), visibility (true/false), etc. I've been there before, learnt the hard way :)